# How to group values in join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One with main data (messages) and second with stats (messages_open_history).

```
messages:
id  | name
1   | m1
2   | m2
3   | m3
4   | m4

messages_open_history:
id | message_id | opened | date
1  |      1     |   0    | 2019-09-01
2  |      1     |   1    | 2019-09-02
3  |      2     |   0    | 2019-09-01
4  |      2     |   0    | 2019-09-02
5  |      2     |   0    | 2019-09-03
6  |      3     |   1    | 2019-09-01
7  |      3     |   0    | 2019-09-02
8  |      4     |   1    | 2019-09-01
```

I would like to check if any Message was opened.

```
id  | name | opened
1   | m1   | 1
2   | m2   | 0
3   | m3   | 1
4   | m4   | 1
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, opened FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN messages_open_history moh
```

Comment: Do you consider "opened" in case exists a record with `opened=1` for a specific message or in case the most recent element of a specific message reports `opened=1`? I got the impression you mean the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
select m.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from messages_open_history moh
                where moh.message_id = m.id and
                      moh.opened = 1
               )
       ) as ever_opened
from messages m;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `messages_open_history(message_id, opened)`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to solve this is using `Max()` aggregation on `opened` field with `Group By`. Now, it seems that `opened` field has only two values either `0` or `1`.

So we can also use `LEFT JOIN` (with condition `opened = 1`) with `DISTINCT`. If the message has not been opened at all, `LEFT JOIN` will result in `NULL`. We can then use [`Coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to consider it as 0.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.id, m.name, COALESCE(moh.opened, 0) AS opened 
FROM messages AS m 
LEFT JOIN messages_open_history AS moh 
       ON moh.message_id = m.id 
          AND moh.opened = 1 
ORDER BY m.id
```

**Result**

```
| id  | name | opened |
| --- | ---- | ------ |
| 1   | m1   | 1      |
| 2   | m2   | 0      |
| 3   | m3   | 1      |
| 4   | m4   | 1      |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kiWkXiKQRQnvCsrXLq8TR4/0)

For good performance, please define the following composite index: `(message_id, opened)` on the `messages_open_history` table.

Comment: @RaymondNijland yeah I fixed that last edit (added demo). Distinct is needed because message history table will have many entries for a message, and I am avoiding `group by`.

Comment: yes message_id/opened combination in the records can be duplicated offcource nevermind mine first comment... The topicstarter didn't say that the case was not possible i was wrongly assuming that only two records existed per message_id..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL v 8.0 or higher, another way to get the correct result is by using window function-

```
SELECT id, name, opened
FROM (SELECT m.id, m.name, moh.opened
            ,row_number() over(partition by m.name order by moh.opened desc) is_open
      FROM messages AS m 
      JOIN messages_open_history AS moh ON moh.message_id = m.id) open_msg
WHERE is_open = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, max(t2.opened)
from messages t1
join messages_open_history t2 on t1.id = t2.message_id
group by t1.id, t1.name
```